# Bibliography: How can I use a date in any field?

Tags: biblatex, date, isodate

Sometimes I would like to use a date in `\titleaddon` or any field, but neither `\printdate` nor `\bibdate` nor `\mkbibdate` ... works, though I've loaded `isodate`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sortlocale=auto, sorting=nyvt,
            alldates=terse, eventdate=comp,
            language=ngerman, origdate=comp,
            datezeros=false,backend=biber,labeldateparts=true,
            autolang=hyphen, clearlang = true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{thebib.bib}
@Book{Kant:KrV,
  author =   {Immanuel Kant},
  title =    {Kritik der reinen Vernunft},
  titleaddon =   {\autocap zuerst vorgelesen am \mydate{1780-07-19}},
  language =     {german},
  year =     1781,
  publisher =    {Hartknoch},
  location =     {Riga}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{thebib.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Other possibilities being

```
\titleaddon{\autocap zuerst vorgelesen am \mydaterange{1780-07-19}{1781-11-07}}

\titleaddon{\autocap zuerst vorgelesen am \mydate{1780-07-19T15:30:00}}
```

for lectures

```
\mydaterange{1780-07-19T15:30:00}{1780-07-19T17:00:00}
```

Comment: How should the date be printed?

Comment: The isodate command `\daterange` does work (I'm not sure how to get it to print the time as well). `\printdate` however is also a command defined by `biblatex`, and it does not take an argument (and apparently biblatex's definition of it takes precedence over isodate's definition).

Comment: @samcarter The date should look like all other dates.

Answer (score 5):

`biblatex` has its own `\printdate` which prints the `date` of the entry. So in citations and the bibliography `isodate`'s `\printdate` is masked by `biblatex`'s definition. The easiest solution is to save `\printdate` in another macro and use that instead.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\let\idprintdate=\printdate
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kant:KrV,
  author     = {Immanuel Kant},
  title      = {Kritik der reinen Vernunft},
  titleaddon = {\autocap{z}uerst vorgelesen am \idprintdate{1780-07-19}},
  language   = {german},
  year       = 1781,
  publisher  = {Hartknoch},
  location   = {Riga},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

You can also use `datetime2`, whose command names don't clash with `biblatex` commands. Instead of `isodate` load

```
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
```

and then use

```
  titleaddon = {\autocap{z}uerst vorgelesen am \DTMdate{1780-07-19}},
```

---

`\bibdate` and `\mkbibdate` are not defined by `biblatex`. There are the macros `\mkbibdatelong` and `\mkbibdateshort`, but you can't use them in this situation, they have to operate on `date`-like fields in the `.bbl`. There are also some macros that begin with `\bibdate...` but those mainly customise the date output by `biblatex`'s macros, they don't print a date themselves.

Comment: `DTMdate` works, but `\DTMtime{14:00:00}` doesn't. It produces the error `Runaway argument?`
[...]
`./Bibliographie.tex:383: Paragraph ended before \@dtm@parsetime was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par`, even though I made `:` inactive as it says in `datetime2.pdf`, p. 15 "Take care if you use babel with a language setting that makes the colon character active. You will have to switch off the shorthands in order to use this command correctly."

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann `titleaddon = {\autocap{z}uerst vorgelesen am \DTMdate{1780-07-19} \DTMtime{14:00:00}},` works brilliantly for me with `\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}` in the above MWE. Please ask a new question with an MWE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: That's not an easy thing to do as my preamble is extremely long. I'll try. I thought there might be something like an escape command so that it doesn't get confused and looks for an end of a paragraph.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Can you use `\DTMtime{14:00:00}` in the document directly, or does that also cause an error? Anyway, with binary search it should be possible to find the culprit rather quickly. (You can *probably* eliminate some packages immediately.)

Comment: I can use it. The other thing I'll try tomorrow as I've changed the format of nearlty everything.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Did you manage to isolate the problem?